# Error on EA Async.Init() in Java / Android

Tags: java, android, async-await

I want to implement async await in my android project and stumbled upon the EA async implementation. The documentation stated that to use await first you have to call "Async.Init()". This call throws an exception with the following stacktrace:

```
08-31 14:38:58.034 25472-25472/com.example.lukge.sensortestE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.lukge.sensortest, PID: 25472
                                                                          java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.init(InitializeAsync.java:225)
                                                                              at com.ea.async.Async.init(Async.java:79)
                                                                              at com.example.lukge.sensortest.measure_jump_activity.onCreate(measure_jump_activity.java:43)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7003)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error attaching ea-async java agent
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.<clinit>(InitializeAsync.java:99)
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.init(InitializeAsync.java:225) 
                                                                              at com.ea.async.Async.init(Async.java:79) 
                                                                              at com.example.lukge.sensortest.measure_jump_activity.onCreate(measure_jump_activity.java:43) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7003) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error activating orbit-async agent
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.loadAgent(InitializeAsync.java:215)
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.<clinit>(InitializeAsync.java:80)
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.init(InitializeAsync.java:225) 
                                                                              at com.ea.async.Async.init(Async.java:79) 
                                                                              at com.example.lukge.sensortest.measure_jump_activity.onCreate(measure_jump_activity.java:43) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7003) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.loadAgent(InitializeAsync.java:164)
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.<clinit>(InitializeAsync.java:80) 
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.init(InitializeAsync.java:225) 
                                                                              at com.ea.async.Async.init(Async.java:79) 
                                                                              at com.example.lukge.sensortest.measure_jump_activity.onCreate(measure_jump_activity.java:43) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7003) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
                                                                              at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.loadAgent(InitializeAsync.java:164) 
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.<clinit>(InitializeAsync.java:80) 
                                                                              at com.ea.async.instrumentation.InitializeAsync.init(InitializeAsync.java:225) 
                                                                              at com.ea.async.Async.init(Async.java:79) 
                                                                              at com.example.lukge.sensortest.measure_jump_activity.onCreate(measure_jump_activity.java:43) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7003) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1230) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
                                                                            Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.lukge.sensortest-MPyaM9__AizWKV2SH41qSA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
                                                                              at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
08-31 14:38:58.034 25472-25472/com.example.lukge.sensortest E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
                                                                              at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
                                                                              at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
                                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:686)
                                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:719)
                                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:947)
                                                                              at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2290)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5904)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1756)
                                                                                    ... 6 more
```

**Hopefully someone can help me out on why it's throwing an exception**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EA Async requires a regular (desktop or server) JVM and is not compatible with Android.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :)